# Problems solving a DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following DE $$\frac{\mathrm{dn} }{\mathrm{d} \theta } = \frac{f'(\theta ) - \alpha }{c'(n)}.$$

By taking the integral on both sides and letting the constants $= 0$, I get $$\theta = \frac{nc'(n)}{f'(\theta) - \alpha}.$$.

This is what I've done: $\int c'(n) dn =  \int \left [ f'(\theta ) - \alpha \right ] d\theta \Rightarrow nc'(n) + K_{n} = \theta f'(\theta) - \alpha \theta + K_{\theta } \Rightarrow nc'(n) = \theta f'(\theta) - \alpha \theta + K_{\theta } - K_{n} \Rightarrow \frac{nc'(n)- K}{f'(\theta)-\alpha} = \theta$.

But I want to get $\theta = \frac{-nc'(n)}{f'(\theta)-\alpha}$.

Where am I going wrong with this?

Comment: $\int c'(n) dn = \int dc(n)  \Rightarrow c(n) + K$. I think that you may have made mistake in your expression about $\int c'(n) dn$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not quite know how you can get what you got.

Start from
$$\frac{\mathrm{dn} }{\mathrm{d} \theta } = \frac{f'(\theta ) - \alpha }{c'(n)} \tag{1}$$

We can get 
$$c'(n)\frac{\mathrm{dn} }{\mathrm{d} \theta } = f'(\theta ) - \alpha  \tag{2}$$

or

$$\frac{\mathrm{dc}}{\mathrm{dn}}\frac{\mathrm{dn} }{\mathrm{d} \theta } = f'(\theta ) - \alpha  \tag{3}$$

$$\frac{\mathrm{dc}}{\mathrm{d} \theta } = f'(\theta ) - \alpha  \tag{4}$$

So integration of (4) leads to
$$c(\theta) = f(\theta) - \alpha \theta +\beta  \tag{5}$$

Setting $\beta=0$, we get

$$\alpha \theta = f(\theta) -c(\theta) \tag{6}$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got from equation (3) to (4). I think the final answer should be $\theta = \frac{f(\theta ) - c(n) + \beta }{\alpha }$.

Comment: we cancel out $dn$ in $\frac{\mathrm{dc}}{\mathrm{dn}}\frac{\mathrm{dn} }{\mathrm{d} \theta }$.  This is the reverse of chain rule. I think that your solution is better. my $c(\theta)$ is equal to your $c(n(\theta))$.

Comment: I think I've figured it out: $c'(n) dn = f'(\theta ) - \alpha d\theta  \Rightarrow c(n) + K_{n} = f(\theta ) - \alpha \theta + K_{\theta} \Rightarrow \theta = \frac{f(\theta ) - c(n) + K}{\alpha }$. Note that $K=K_{n}+K_{\theta}$.

Comment: Yes.  But you have a typo. It should be $c'(n) dn = f'(\theta )d\theta - \alpha d\theta $

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is put all $n$'s on one side and all $\theta$'s on the other.  Then you can integrate both sides.

Comment: Yes, I've done that. I'll make an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your differential equation can be solved writing

$$
 c'(n) dn = (f'(\theta) -\alpha ) d\theta 
$$

Now you can integrate both sides between $n_1, n_2$ and $\theta_1, \theta_2 $, to obtain

$$
\theta_2 - \theta_1 = \frac{1}{\alpha} \left [ f(\theta_2) - f(\theta_1) - (c(n_2)-c(n_1) \right ]
$$